# Cakephp 3 - Building an entity over several forms/actions

Tags: cakephp

This is a design question.

I'm trying to build a booking system in cakephp3.

I've never done something like this with cake before.

I thought the best way might be to -- as the post title suggests -- build up an entity over several forms/actions.

Something like choose location -> enter customer details -> enter special requirements -> review full details and pay

So each of those stages becomes an action within my booking controller. The view for each action submits its content to the next action in the chain, and i use patch entity with the request data, and send the result to the new action's view.

I've started to wonder if this is a good way to do it. One significant problem is that the data from each of the previous actions has to be stored in hidden fields so that it can be resubmitted with the new data from the current action.

I want the data from previous actions to be visible in a read only fashion so I've used the entity that i pass to the view to fill an HTML table. That's nice and it works fine but having to also store that same data in hidden fields is not a very nice way to do it.

I hope this is making sense!

Anyway, I thought I'd post on here for some design guidance as i feel like there is probably a better way to do this. I have considered creating temporary records in the database and just passing the id but i was hoping I wouldn't have to.

Any advice here would be very much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: If you don't want to store it in the DB and pass the id there is almost only the session left. You could store it in the browsers local storage as well via JS but I don't think this is a very reliable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just store the entity in the DB and then proceed with your other views, getting data from the DB. Pseudo:

```
    public function chooseLocation() {
        $ent = new Entitiy();

        patchEntity($ent,$this->request->data);
        if save entity {
            redirect to enterCustomerDetails($ent[id]);
        }
    }

   public function enterCustomerDetails($id) {
     $ent = $this->Modelname->get($id);
     // patch, save, redirect again ...
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks to both of you for your responses. I've done it the way you suggest and it works well. It was quite quick to set up and the only problem i had was fixed by removing a couple of validation rules. Cheers

Comment: glad i could help :) Cheers